# Array Select в php

Tags: php, массивы

Предположи у меня есть массив такого формата.

Я хочу выбрать к примеру с ключом "2019-05-13", как мне сделать чтобы выбирался он("2019-05-13"), предыдущий("2019-05-12"), и последующий ("2019-05-14")

```
"2019-05-09" => array:3 [▶]
"2019-05-10" => array:3 [▶]
"2019-05-11" => array:3 [▶]
"2019-05-12" => array:3 [▶]
"2019-05-13" => array:3 [▶]
"2019-05-14" => array:3 [▶]
"2019-05-15" => array:3 [▶]
"2019-05-16" => array:3 [▶]
"2019-05-17" => array:3 [▶]
"2019-05-18" => array:3 [▶]
"2019-05-19" => array:3 [▶]
"2019-05-20" => array:3 [▶]
```

Comment: откуда берется массив?

Comment: да, забавно. prev/next есть, а указатель на текущий ключ чтобы установить надо перебрать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$a = [
    "2019-05-10" => 1,
    "2019-05-11" => 2,
    "2019-05-12" => 3,
    "2019-05-13" => 4,
    "2019-05-14" => 5,
];

$pos = array_search('2019-05-12', array_keys($a));
print_r(array_slice($a, $pos-1, 3));
```

На краевые условия проверьте самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но это больше на кастыль похоже, нужно что-то более изящное

Comment: Как найдете - поделитесь "изяществом".

Comment: @BruAPAHE мы здесь не на вернисаже. Или приведите критерий "изящности", или поблагодарите автора за ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @Ипатьев его поблагодарили без ваших подсказок.